# Сравнение двух массивов vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В компоненте есть два массива:

Первый (`region`):

```
[
   { name: "Москва" },
   { name: "Екатеринбург" }
]
```

Второй (`deliveryTime`):

```
[
  { name: "Екатеринбург", delivery_time: "2-7" },
  { name: "Москва", delivery_time: "1-3"}
]
```

Если из первого массива выбран, скажем, город Москва, нужно подставлять время доставки (в данном случае 1-3).

Что получилось сделать:

```
<div v-for="(reg, index) in deliveryTime" :key="index"> 
   <span :class="{"reg": findTime(reg)}"> {{ reg.delivery_time }} -- {{ reg.name }} </span>
</div>

methods: {
  findTime(reg) {
    return this.region.includes(reg);
  }
}
```

Нужно оставить только время доставки и название города (скриншот: Екатерибург, время доставки: 5-8). Как можно улучшить/переписать код, дабы добиться того, что требуется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Куда подставлять-то?

Comment: @yar85 В тот же див/спан (можно вместо ```{{ reg }}}```)

Comment: Все равно нипанятна)) У тебя сейчас выводятся все элементы второго массива, то есть не соблюдается условие задачи "Если из первого массива выбран". Допустим, сделаем вывод по условию истинности значения свойства `active` соотв. элемента в массиве `region` - а с остальными элементами массива как?

Comment: Но в любом случае, я бы предложил тут вместо массивов использовать хэштаблицы, у элементов которых ключом является название города.

Comment: @yar85 Я отредактировал первое сообщение, возможно, так станет понятно, что мне нужно?

Comment: Увы, это "мне нужно" не проясняет конкретно указанную выше неясность с логикой задачи... Выводиться должен один город, или все (как на скриншоте)? Если все, то что именно не устраивает в текущем варианте? А если только один элемент выводить, то по какому принципу фильтровать нужный при том что в обоих массивах тут идентичный набор городов? Логика свойства `active` не описана... возможно, описание роли и порядка изменения его значения как-то прояснит общий принцип получения желаемого результата.

Comment: Может ты хочешь отфильтровать массив `deliveryTime` по значению свойства `active` элементов массива `region` с совпадающим значением `name`?

Comment: @yar85 так, забыли про ```active```, это было лишнее из одного из кодов, которые я пытался сделать. Попробую иначе объяснить: у меня есть выпадашка, в ней список ВСЕХ городов, там я выбираю город. В зависимости КАКОЙ город выбран (город 1 выбран), в блоке с доставкой должны выводиться количество дней доставки (в зависимости какой город выбран - 1)

Comment: Ладно, забыли. Надо вывести все элементы `deliveryTime` у которых значение `name` совпадает со значением `name` одного из элементов `region` - так что ли? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача до конца не ясна... но класс таких задач (предполагающих "`v-for` по части элементов коллекции") в Vue решается через вычисляемое свойство:

```
<div v-for="dt in selectedRegionsDeliveryTime" :key="dt.name"> 
  <span>{{ dt.delivery_time }} -- {{ dt.name }}</span>
</div>

computed: {
  selectedRegions() {
    return this.region.reduce((rslt, { name }) => rslt.add(name), new Set());
  },
  selectedRegionsDeliveryTime() {
    return this.deliveryTime.filter(dt => this.selectedRegions.has(dt.name));
  },
},
```

Тут выводятся все элементы `deliveryTime` у которых значение `name` совпадает со значением `name` одного из элементов `region`.

Вспомогательное свойство `selectedRegions` введено только для того чтобы на каждой итерации `filter` повторно не перебирать весь массив `region` (в котором мешается еще и совершенно бесполезная обертка каждого значения в объект).
Ключом `v-for` лучше брать свойство перебираемых в этом цикле объектов, с уникальным значением (использование индекса элемента коллекции в качестве ключа - плохая практика).

---

Если же нужен только один элемент массива `deliveryTime`, то все еще проще - т.к. значение для его поиска уже есть (предполагается) в компоненте, и остается добавить к нему только вычисляемое свойство возвращающее результат `find`:

```
<div v-if="Boolean(selectedRegion)">
  <span>{{ curDeliveryTime.delivery_time }} -- {{ curDeliveryTime.name }}</span>
</div>

data() { return {
  selectedRegion: null,    // "выбранный" в UI регион (присваивать элемент массива `region`)
  /* .... */
}},
computed: {
  curDeliveryTime() {
    return this.deliveryTime.find(dt => dt.name === this.selectedRegion.name);
  },
},
```

Comment: 2ой способ подошел, чуть переиначил. Спасибо. :)